# ¿Cómo pasar datos obtenidos de un TextField a un método de otra clase?

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextfield

Tengo un campo de TextField en una interfaz de usuario que simula un juego para que ingrese un núemro de jugadores y después utilizar esa información en otro bloque de código pero en otra clase para empezar a jugar con el número de participantes insertado por el usuario.

```
String noJugadores;
    noJugadores=this.txtNoJugadores.getText();
```

aquí recibo la información, pero, qué función debo hacer para pasarlo a otro método en otra clase y así poder hacer uso de esa información.

Comment: a que te referis con que funcion? tu problema es q no sabes pasar datos entre clases?

Comment: así es exactamente, pasar los datos a otro método en otra clase

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es pasar un ese dato de una Clase A a una Clase B? Si obtienes ese valor de un método, podrías hacer que la clase B herede de la clase A y así obtienes sin problema ese valor o cómo dicen puedes crear un Objeto de la clase A en tu clase B y así poder acceder a tu dato, pero debes de ser public para poder acceder a él o tener sus respectivos getter y setter.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente si el campo que esperas es el número de jugadores, ese campo NO debe ser String sino Integer, por ahí comenzamos a trabajar, luego analizamos la importancia del campo en la otra clase, en este caso creo que la clase B por llamarla de alguna forma necesita obligatoriamente este parámetro para construir el juego y comenzar utilizando este valor, por lo que debemos poner la variable de la clase A publica para acceder a ella desde cualquier parte.

Ejemplo Clase_A:

```
//declaro e inicializo la variable noJugadores
public int noJugadores = 0; 
... 
//luego le asignamos el valor a la variable
noJugadores = Integer.parseInt(txtNoJugadores.getText());
```

Ejemplo Clase_B:

```
Clase_A init = new Clase_A();
this.startGame(init.noJugadores);
```

Eso es todo...

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar datos de una clase a otra, simplemente sobre la instancia de la clase que va a recibir los datos has:

```
claserecibidora.dato1 = dato;
```

Deberás tener la clase que va a recibir los datos instancia y dentro del ambito desde donde los vas a enviar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes sobrecargar el constructor de la clase que recibira el dato y luego se lo asignas a una variable de instancia.

Ejemplo :

```
public class Clase1
{
    public static void main(String ... args)
    {
        //tu logica debe ir aqui

        String noJugadores;
        //noJugadores=this.txtNoJugadores.getText();

        noJugadores = "10";
        Clase2 clase2 = new Clase2(noJugadores);

    }

}

public class Clase2 
{
    private String dato ;

    public Clase2(String dato)
    {
        this.dato = dato;
    }

}
```

Espero te sirva y Saludos.

Comment: coloca un ejemplo de código con lo que mencionas :D

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente crea una instancia de ese objeto.

```
TuOtraClase otraClase = new TuOtraClase;
otraClase.inicarJuego(txtNoJugadores.getText());
```

puesto que me imagino que tu parametro de tu clase pide un entero y tu le estás mandado ahí cadena puedes hacer lo siguiente para transformar el texto en entero

```
try {
  otraClase.inicarJuego(Integer.parseInt(txtNoJugadores.getText()));
} catch(Exception e) {
  JoptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(this, "ingresa solo numeros");
}
```